# Postgres. Что значит сообщение: неполный стартовый пакет

Tags: postgresql

У меня Postgres 9.6 Portable.

При старте приложения(Не самой базы, а именно разрабатываемого приложения, работающего с ней) постоянно сыпет в консоль сообщения (Примерно раз в 8-10 секунд):

> СООБЩЕНИЕ: неполный стартовый пакет

В целом все отлично работает, но эти сообщения мозолят мне глаза. Плюс постепенно вытесняют сообщения консоли из области экрана.

Что это значит и как это можно отключить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в логе сервера ничего нету?

Comment: Это вроде он и есть. Не уверен что знаю как посмотреть, если это не он.

Comment: Если он portable, думаю, надо глянуть где-то в папке с ним. Либо в каталоге с БД. Можно в `postgresql.conf` посмотреть. И там же, возможно переопределить куда будет выводиться. Если я всё правильно понял, то можно добиться, чтобы вместо консоли выводилось в файл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Как воспроизводится данное сообщение

Необходимо послать пакет, который просто проверяет доступность порта, не открывая полноценного соединения с PostgreSQL, например с помощью nmap:

```
nmap -Pn -p 5432 localhost
```

что в свою очередь будет отображено в логе как `LOG:  incomplete startup packet` (СООБЩЕНИЕ: неполные стартовый пакет)

```
sudo tailf /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-9.4-main.log
2017-09-08 10:47:05 MSK [16539-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2017-09-08 10:47:05 MSK [16539-2] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
```

Таким образом можно сделать вывод, что причина в разрабатываемом приложении, которое в какой-то момент лишь проверяет, но не создаёт соединение с PostgreSQL.

По материалам: http://www.postgresql-archive.org/Incomplete-startup-packet-help-needed-td5199030.html

Comment: Значит это просто обычный `heartbeat`. Благодарю, хотябы понятно откуда взялось.